# ¿Existe un framework MVC con PHP básico?

Tags: php, mvc

He visto que existen varios frameworks en PHP como *CakePHP*, *Codeigniter*, *Laravel*, etc., pero todos tienen muchos componentes que a fin de cuentas son espacio en disco y que por lo general no se ocupan todos. Por tal razón quisiera saber si alguien tiene una referencia a frameworks más ligeros, específicos y funcionales que me puedan proporcionar.

Comment: Lo de ligeros entonces es porque ocuparán menos disco en vez de por consumir menos recursos (RAM, procesador, ...), ¿no? Lo de específicos... ¿para qué función? y lo de funcionales... no porque ocupen menos espacio van a dar más funcionalidad... la lógica incluso diría que debería ser al contrario. No lo tomes a mal pero esta pregunta es demasiado ambigua y laxa.

Comment: Hola @JclunaOficial. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Si bien puede ser interesante, la pregunta busca respuestas basadas en opiniones. Esto es algo que se intenta evitar en el sitio. La idea es realizar preguntas que tengan una respuesta única válida, que no dependa de lo que un solo desarrollador haya realizado o prefiera. Quizás te sea útil leer [ask]. La alternativa es preguntar en el [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol).

Comment: No hay problema @eferion, te amplio los conceptos: [ligeros] menos componentes por ende menos recursos (ram,proc,hd); [especifico] (aquí una disculpa por no ser mas detallado) para crear web app (no restful, ws, api); [funcional] que ya se haya probado con éxito y no requiera cambios constantes en la base.

Comment: Insisto, que un framework tenga mil componentes no implica que los mil se carguen a la vez luego eso no tienen por qué traducirse necesariamente en un mayor consumo de RAM y mucho menos de procesador. Es un error pensar eso sin datos objetivos

Comment: Considero que en el caso de frameworks, no deberias buscar uno de menor peso sino uno de mayor rendimiento, cada framework trae pros y contras pero si buscas uno ligero, te recomiendo utilizar `PHALCON` puesto que a diferencia de otros frameworks, cuenta con la estructura de un framework comun pero no necesitas descargar carpetas, etc, solo es cuestion de bajar un .dll y modificar en la configuracion del php.ini y ya puedes trabajar como un framework normal.... te dejo un enlace a la pagina... (https://phalconphp.com/es/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con Slim,

https://www.slimframework.com/
"Slim is a PHP micro framework that helps you quickly write simple yet powerful web applications and APIs. "